# Merging multiple meshes with one mesh without them merging with each other

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, boolean-modifier

[image: 3D model of hand]

I'm trying to model a hand and I have put together this one, which is comprised of one palm and five fingers, each as their own mesh/object. I need to merge each finger to the palm so that I can smooth out the area where the fingers connect to the palm, but the fingers overlap slightly, and if I were to use the boolean modifier, the fingers would merge with each other (effectively gluing the fingers together for when I rig them). Are there any quick ways to attach them to the palm without attaching everything else together?

Comment: Hello, I think It will be easier to extrude the fingers from the palm